# How to run SQL job on specific dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job, sql-job

So I have a job that I would like to have run on the first friday of a fiscal calendar. In this case, the first friday of the fiscal calendar month does not always match up with the actual calendar month. Thus, I need to have the job run on specified dates that are generated by the fiscal calendar dates.

I do have a list of the dates that it needs to be run on, but I'm unsure on how exactly to implement this logic. On the SSMS interface, I don't see anywhere that we can define a custom schedule.

From my understanding I would have to somehow create a custom schedule off of a fiscal calendar table, and then use that in the job. Is that correct? How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: You can set up a simple schedule, like each Friday to run a stored procedure and within this stored procedure implement your complex logic for checking the custom calendar table. So, the procedure will run more often than needed, but will perform the actual work only when needed.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Oh I see, something like `IF CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = FirstFiscalFriday, -- run job`, correct?

Comment: Yes. You can have two separate stored procedures. One that does the actual work. And another that is scheduled to run often and has a logic inside it to check the calendar and call the first procedure only on the days when needed. So, the schedule for the SQL Server Agent that runs the jobs remains simple, the complexity is hidden in your T-SQL code.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov  got it, thanks!